# Python OpenCV - How to recognize the specific colour in the image

Tags: python, opencv

Hello all I am working on the program that will simply recognize % of violet colour in the image. I am struggling with this rgb values.. Is there any smarter way of predefined static values for colours like 'blue' or 'green' or 'violet' in openCV already?

This is the code and the picture

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

imagePath = "probki/b.png"
img = cv2.imread(imagePath)

violet = [84, 39, 60]

diff = 100

boundaries = [([violet[2], violet[1]-diff, violet[0]-diff],
           [violet[2]+diff, violet[1]+diff, violet[0]+diff])]

scalePercent = 1

width = int(img.shape[1] * scalePercent)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scalePercent)
newSize = (width, height)

img = cv2.resize(img, newSize, None, None, None, cv2.INTER_AREA)

cv2.imshow("img resized", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

for (lower, upper) in boundaries:

    lower = np.array(lower, dtype=np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype=np.uint8)

    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

    cv2.imshow("binary mask", mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow("ANDed mask", output)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    ratio_violet = cv2.countNonZero(mask)/(img.size/3)

    colorPercent = (ratio_violet * 100) / scalePercent

    print('violet pixel percentage:', np.round(colorPercent, 2))

    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: purple on gray to recognize]

Comment: you have this predefined ones https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dba/classcv_1_1viz_1_1Color.html

Comment: cvtColor, work in HSL or HSV space. use inRange to select hues and saturations. there you have a mask.